# Conjectured count of monogenic rings of fixed rank

Tags: nt.number-theory, algebraic-number-theory

By a *monogenic ring of rank $n$* we mean a ring $R = \mathbb{Z}[\theta]$, where $\theta$ is an algebraic integer of degree $n$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. Put $f_\theta(x)$ for the minimal polynomial of $\theta$; it is necessarily a monic polynomial with integer coefficients.

By the *discriminant* of $R$ we mean the discriminant of $\Delta(f_\theta)$ of $f_\theta$. Counting monogenic rings of fixed rank ordered by discriminant is a difficult problem for all $n \geq 3$; for example, the $n = 3$ case is roughly equivalent to the problem of counting elliptic curves $E/\mathbb{Q}$ of bounded discriminant, a notorious open problem.

Is there a conjectured asymptotic formula for the number $M_n(X)$ of monogenic rings of rank $n$ ordered by discriminant?

Comment: Probably one conjectures that the number of such rings with discriminant $<D$ is the volume of the space of monic degree $n$ polynomials with discriminant $<D$ (modulo changes of variables) times the product over $p$ of the fraction of monic degree $n$ polynomials over $\mathbb Z_p$ that define regular rings.

Comment: X^{1/2 + 1/n}, no? I haven’t bothered thinking about the difference between the rank n ring case and just counting monogenic number fields, so forgive me if it’s wildly wrong.